# How can I "Share To" a network folder from my photo gallery?

Tags: wi-fi, file-system, share-menu

I have an HTC Thunderbolt running Ice Cream Sandwich

If I open up my photo gallery and tap on a picture, the "Share" option appears.

Clicking on this gives me some options, such as Facebook, Instagram, Google Drive, etc.

I recently setup a shared folder with my Netgear ReadyShare router that uses Samba. I am able to use the ES File Explorer app to successfully connect to my samba drive and access my folders/files.

How do I setup a "Share To" option that will allow me to copy my photos to my shared samba drive?